# Сортировка массивов с удалением повторяющихся строк

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! 
Возникла задача на сортировку. Есть 2 файла с набором строк (приблизительно 1000), в каждой из которых хранится число например 345234123 (9 знаков - самое большое число) . Нужно сравнить два массива и во втором удалить все строки , имеющиеся в первом массиве. как это можно сделать?

```html
$array1 = file('Yalta.txt');
$array2 = file('Exclude.txt');

$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
foreach ($array1 as $array1) {

 echo $array1.'<br>';
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: почему стоит две метки?

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев - он пробовал задать вопрос на http://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php поможет? Только порциями наверное желательно сделать это

Comment: @Igor это конечно круто :)))) Но при возникающих проблемах лучше попытаться их решить самому, а не писать сразу сюда :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а чойта пхп, там javascript метка стоит :)

Comment: @Grundy не только лишь js

Comment: Алексей , эта функция хороша, но у меня два файла больше 1000 строк каждый. Я так понял что тут нужно каждый элемент вручную прописать в массив.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Добавил код. Вобщем остался только один вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы записать всё в таком же формате в файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Работает как file, только обрезает пробельные символы с начала/конца и исключает пустые строки
 *
 * @param string $name Имя файла
 *
 * @return array Массив НЕ пустых строк, разделённых по переносу
 */
function getFile($name){
    $data = [];
    array_map(function($str) use (&$data){
        $str = trim($str);
        if(strlen($str) > 0)
            $data[] = $str;
    }, file($name));

    return $data;
}

// Читаем через функцию выше, иначе '123' и '123\n' будут разными числами
$f = getFile('1.txt');
$s = getFile('2.txt');
// Из второго файла вычитаем первый, тогда второй будет содержать только уникальные строки
$data = array_diff($s, $f);

$f = fopen('3.txt', 'w');
fwrite($f, implode("\n", $data));
fclose($f);

// Пример
// 1.txt
123
456

789
// 2.txt
123
000
789
999
// 3.txt
000
999
```

Comment: Спасибо. Буду использовать

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант, такой пример кода:

```
$array1 = file('Yalta.txt');
$array2 = file('Exclude.txt');

$filename  =  "Res.txt";
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

 //$other_mass = serialize($result);
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
//fwrite($handle,  $other_mass);

fwrite($handle,implode('',$result));
fclose($handle);
```